# How to send email attachments using python httplib2 with Mailgun

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, mailgun, httplib2

I am using httplib2 with the Mailgun API to send an email attachment which I downloaded using the Google Drive, the email is sending but without attachments.. below is my code..

```
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

        request = DRIVE.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType='application/pdf')

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)

        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
            logging.info("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))

        messages = {
            "from": sender,
            "to": recipient,
            "subject": 'Attachment Mail from Mailgun',
            "text": 'Testing',
            "attachment": fh.getvalue()
        }

         url = URL

        data = {
            "from": messages['from'],
            "to": messages['to'],
            "subject": messages['subject'],
            "text": messages['text'],
            "attachment": messages['attachment']
        }

        pl = urllib.urlencode(data)

        http = httplib2.Http()
        http.add_credentials('api', API)

        resp, content = http.request(
            url, 'POST', pl,
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"})
```

Answer (score 1):

We use the `mailgun` API to send emails using `Appengine` and reading from `cloud storage`, the same principles will apply to `google drive`:

The first thing I would suggest is looking into [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html). It allows you to simulate working with files inside the appengine sandbox in an easier way than BytesIO, but both produce what python calls `file objects` that support `.read()` so this should work with both.

Once you have your file as a `file like object`, you just need to pass it correctly to the API. The following example uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library as it makes it really easy to POST with files and is compatible with appengine.

Notice that in this case `open(FILE_PATH_1, 'rb')` is a `file like object`, you just need to replace that with your file object:

```
def send_complex_message():
    return requests.post("https://api.mailgun.net/v2/DOMAIN/messages",
          auth=("api", "key-SECRET"),
          files={
              "attachment[0]": ("FileName1.ext", open(FILE_PATH_1, 'rb')),
              "attachment[1]": ("FileName2.ext", open(FILE_PATH_2, 'rb'))
          },
          data={"from": "FROM_EMAIL",
                "to": [TO_EMAIL],
                "subject": SUBJECT,
                "html": HTML_CONTENT
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def send_mailgun(to, subject, html, file, file_name, cc, bcc):
    MAILGUN_URL='https://api.mailgun.net/v3/DOMAIN/messages'
    MAILGUN_KEY='key-secret'

    data = {
        "subject": subject,
        "from": "FROM_EMAIL",
        "to": to,
        "html": html
    }

    if cc != "":
        data["cc"] = cc

    if bcc != "":
        data["bcc"] = bcc

    if file_name and file_name != "":
        resp = requests.post(
            MAILGUN_URL,
            auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
            files=[("attachment", (file_name,file))],
            data=data
        )
    else:
        resp = requests.post(
            MAILGUN_URL,
            auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
            data=data
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late though... I solved this long time ago.. below was what I did:

```
import io
import base64
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
from libs.poster.encode import multipart_encode, MultipartParam

from oauth2client.appengine import AppAssertionCredentials
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http

request = drive.files().export_media(fileId=spreadsheet_id, mimeType='application/pdf')

        fh = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)

        done = False
        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

        message = {
            'from': 'noreply',
            'to': 'recipient',
            'subject': mail_subject,
            'text': text,
            'filename': filename,
            'attachment': fh.getvalue()
        }

        # send email using mailgun
        resp = send_attachment_email(message)


# Compose an email with an attachment
def send_attachment_email(messages):

url = 'mailgun_api_url'
api = 'api-key'

load = {
    "from": messages['from'],
    "to": messages['to'],
    "subject": messages['subject'],
    "text": messages['text'],
    "attachment": MultipartParam(
        "attachment",
        filename=messages['filename'],
        filetype='application/pdf',
        value=messages['attachment'])
}

payload, hd = multipart_encode(load)

hd['Authorization'] = 'Basic %s' % (base64.b64encode(api),)

resp = urlfetch.fetch(url=url, payload="".join(payload), method='POST',
                      headers=hd, validate_certificate=True)
logging.info(resp.status_code)
logging.info(resp.content)

return resp.status_code
```